# Calculate total values when summarising grouped data

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, summarize

I have a dataframe where I have grouped data, I am running summary statistics by group but also want to get summary statistics for everything combined. Is there a simpler way of doing it than doing it twice and combining like follows?

```
dataDF <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 10),
  value1 = rnorm(30),
  value2 = 1:30
)

grouped <- dataDF %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(
    mean1 = mean(value1),
    mean2 = mean(value2),
    sd1 = sd(value1),
    sd2 = sd(value2),
    max1 = max(value1),
    max2 = max(value2)
    )

total <- dataDF %>%
  summarise(
    mean1 = mean(value1),
    mean2 = mean(value2),
    sd1 = sd(value1),
    sd2 = sd(value2),
    max1 = max(value1),
    max2 = max(value2)
  )

combined <- rbind(
  grouped,
  data.frame(
    group = 'All',
    total
  ))

> combined
# A tibble: 4 x 7
  group  mean1 mean2   sd1   sd2  max1  max2
  <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a      0.336  14.5 1.15   9.08  1.98    28
2 b     -0.215  15.5 1.17   9.08  1.30    29
3 c      0.332  16.5 0.874  9.08  2.19    30
4 All    0.151  15.5 1.07   8.80  2.19    30
```

Comment: No, there's not. But using `summarise_all` as mysteRious shows can simplify your code a lot.

Comment: See [Grouping sets, Rollup and Cube for dplyr](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/236#issuecomment-277081375): "_I think these are useful, but are relatively complicated to implement and low on my priority list. Realistically, they're unlikely to get implement in dplyr, so I think it's better to accept that and encourage people to tackle elsewhere_",where 'elsewhere' could be e.g. [`data.table::groupingsets`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.11.8/topics/groupingsets), [some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+groupingsets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a function to do this

```
summarise_with_total <- function(data, func, ...){

  # Gets the cohorts which the DF is grouped by
  cohorts <- groups(data)

  # Results split by cohorts
  split <- data %>% 
    func(...) %>% 
    data.frame()

  # results combined
  combined <- data.frame(
    setNames(data.frame(matrix(data = "All",
                               ncol = length(cohorts),
                               nrow = 1)),
             cohorts),
    ungroup(data) %>% 
      func(...)
  )

  return(rbind(split, combined))

}

dataDF %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise_with_total(summarise_at,
                      .vars = c('value1', 'value2'), 
                      .funs = funs(mean, sd, max))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `summarise_all`?

```
> dataDF %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise_all(funs(mean,sd,max))
# A tibble: 3 x 7
  group value1_mean value2_mean value1_sd value2_sd value1_max value2_max
  <fct>       <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 a          -0.170        14.5     0.938      9.08       1.01        28.
2 b           0.196        15.5     0.771      9.08       1.46        29.
3 c          -0.137        16.5     0.922      9.08       2.10        30.
```

Comment: This is a big improvement on OP's code, but I think their main question is combining summaries at different grouping levels (grouped by `group` and grouped by nothing).